# Is it Possible to Access a Smartphone's Bluetooth from the Browser?

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" but am posing this question in case I've missed some recent tech.

I know native apps can use device bluetooth on both iOS and Android, is there a way to do the same from the browser?

I'm running a node.js web application and want it to be able to communicate with a Raspberry Pi over Bluetooth from a smartphone's browser. Any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web Bluetooth api is in development, but is not widely supported. Notably, support in Safari does not seem to be coming anytime soon.

Source: https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md